# How to uninstall https_Downloader.exe/BitComet entirely?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I was trying to test out my vpn to see if they allow p2p/torrent. So I installed Bitcomet temporary and did a sample download. After I was done I uninstalled Bitcomet using there default uninstaller. The program doesn't show in the program list any more afterword, but it still shows in the Notification Area Icons setting. Plus i also notice that another program was installed called https_Downloader.exe. I'm not sure if it was a Virus or Trojan, but I found out it came from bitcomet (http://tiny.cc/fo0l2x). Is there anyway to uninstall these 2 programs completely? I couldn't find an uninstaller for http_Downloader.exe which concern me a lot. Thanks!

Screenshot of the Notification Area Icon window showing Bitcomet and http_downloader.exe even when it is uninstalled Note:the BitComet.exe icon was actully the logo of bitcomet when I first check it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq6Uy.jpg

Other things to note:

- There wasn't any option about http_downloader.exe when installing
  Bitcomet
- Firefox browser was hijack (Just change homepage)
- I unchecked all the options that look like bloatware/viruses to me
  (like browser integration)
- ADWcleaner, Malware Byte, and Windows Defender didn't find anything.
- I did restart.
- I'm on Windows 8.
- When I first saw http_downlaoder.exe it it was in the notification
  with a "shooting star" icon downloading something. I exit it the
  first time i saw it.

Update:
Tried Rovo Uninstaller (didn't work)